# Scroll bar goes up

Tags: css

I have a chatbox in my website but everytime I type a message.
the scroll bar goes up.
how do I make it be fixed at the bottom like chatting in facebook.

this is the css

```
 .chat-messages {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    height: 550px;
    max-height: 550px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: can't be done with CSS only. Post the whole code. Javascript and HTML

Answer (score 1):

for this you need to use javascript. every time you enter a message or you receive a message you have to scroll to bottom in javascript

try this (if you use jquery):

```
var textarea = $(".chat-messages");
if(textarea.length)
   textarea[0].scrollTop = textarea[0].scrollHeight;
```

if you do not use jquery add an id to your textarea and then do this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```